# Image clip to text

Tags: css, svg, raphael, snap.svg

How can I clip an image to text? I would prefer a method that is available in any browser. I tried background-clip but it not available in all modern browsers.

[image]

Comment: I accepted your answer and will reformulate the requirements in a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a clip-path to an image and you'll see a clipped image.

I've made it look more like your example by adding an additional copy of the image with low opacity behind the clipped image.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="sample" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
       <text x="85" y="330" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="380" font-weight="bold">I CAM</text>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>

  <image transform="scale(0.4)" xlink:href="http://netghost.narod.ru/gff/sample/images/png/marble24.png" x="20" y="20" width="1419" height="1001" opacity="0.3" />
  <image transform="scale(0.4)" xlink:href="http://netghost.narod.ru/gff/sample/images/png/marble24.png" x="20" y="20" width="1419" height="1001" clip-path="url(#sample)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it, but this also has to be responsive, and I am not sure how this text would break to a new line.

Comment: If you want it responsive add a viewBox but that's another question. SVG has no line breaking but you could clip to some foreignObject html text.